# Как считать массив из файла?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Программа должна считывать массив из файла и искать в нём минимальный элемент, но что-то не получается нормально считать сам массив. В чем проблема?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include "fstream"
using namespace std;



void main()
{
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    int array[5];
    in >> array[5];
    int min = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    out << min;
    in.close();
    out.close();

}
```

Файл **input.txt** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Читать надо поэлементно в цикле, и разделители по умолчанию — символы пробельной группы (запятая в них не входит). Ну, и еще в коде выход за пределы массива. Индексы начинаются с 0, т.е. элемента `array[5]` не существует.

Comment: @alexolut , я, вроде как, `array[5]` и не использую, тк в цикле i строго меньше 5

Comment: Начнем с того, что `in >> array[5];` - это считать одно число в шестой элемент массива...

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
void main()
{
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::vector<int> numbers{};
    std::string line{};
    std::string number{};
    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        std::stringstream strStream(line);
        while (std::getline(strStream, number, ','))
        {
            numbers.push_back(atoi(number.c_str()));
        }

    }
    auto result = std::min_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    if (result != numbers.end())
    {
        cout << "minimum is: " << *result;
        ofstream out("output.txt");
        out << *result;
        out.close();

    }
    in.close();
}
```